# Java execute command in OSX

Tags: java, macos, exec

I have a command that works no problem when typed into the terminal although I would like to execute it from a java program.
I am using this code where "homedir" was found from typing in the terminal `which spark`.

```
String homedir = "/usr/local/bin/spark";
File wd = new File(homedir);
Process pwd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("spark", null, wd);
```

When I run the code though I still get an error: `Cannot run program "spark" (in directory "/usr/local/bin"): error=2, No such file or directory`

What am I missing that is stopping this from working?

Answer (score 0):

Run `ls -lah /usr/local/bin/spark` and you may find that it is a symlink that points elsewhere. If so, you need to specify that as the working dir. You can get that path in Java also by saying `wd.getCanonicalPath()`.

Alternatively, use Process pwd = `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/local/bin/spark/spark");` if that is an option.

So to specify an argument you can say:
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/local/bin/spark/spark list");`

To read a result back, use something like:
You can just say `.exec("/usr/local/bin/spark/spark");` To get the result, just use something like:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        pwd.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Using `.exec("/usr/local/bin/spark/spark");` seems to remove the error but returns nothing. How would I be able to send in different strings with this? For example "spark list" or "spark call...".
Running `ls -lah /usr/local/bin/spark` gives me a new path `/usr/local/bin/spark -> ../lib/node_modules/spark-cli/bin/spark.js`. Although changing to this directory also gives me the same old error.

Comment: @StudBeefpile I have updated my answer to have more detail. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: So trying `wd.getCanonicalPath()` doesn't seem to get my any different of a path. I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly though: `wd.getCanonicalPath();` I've also tried: `File path = new File(wd.getCanonicalPath());`
For ttrying to run `.exec("/usr/local/bin/spark/spark");` I get returned: `Cannot run program "/usr/local/bin/spark/spark": error=20, Not a directory`.
I'm totally stumped.